# How to read-only user in postgresql for existing schemas and future new schemas?

Tags: database, postgresql, schema, database-schema, database-permissions

I am using postgresql database. I need a new user who can only read from database. I have searched for creating new user with read only permissions. But all of them are for specific schemas. How can i manage database such that if new schema is added user will have automatic permission to read permission of all the tables in new schema too.

Comment: In Postgres 14+ there is `pg_read_all_data` role from here:  [Predefined roles](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/predefined-roles.html)